# When is it good to use inclusive vs exclusive ranges?

Tags: ruby, range

Is there a reason to use an inclusive range instead of exclusive range or vice versa? Is it better to use this:

```
for i in 1..10
    puts i
end
```

or this:

```
for i in 1...11
    puts i
end
```

or are they just two ways of representing the exact same thing?

Comment: they are certainly two ways of representing the same thing, for example if you wanted to iterate n times you might use `(0...n).each` instead of `(0..n-1).each`. But, then again, you could always use `n.times do` in that case. Basically, I would advise keeping in mind that it exists should a need arise, but know that it's never really necessary.

Comment: I would say it's *never* (or almost never) a good idea to use an exclusive (three-dot) range. Consider `(1...n).include?(x)` versus `(1..n-1).include?(x)`, when the intent is to test `1 <= x <= n-1`. As @Tadman points out, they are not the same when `n` is a `Float`. If `n` is an integer, yes, the two expressions are equivalent, but what if it is decided to change `n` to a `Float` some time in the future? The second form protects against that. Another consideration is that it's very easy--too easy, imo--to mistake 3 dots for 2. And what is the advantage of 3 dots here? To save 1 character?...

Comment: ...Months after you've written the code, you (or someone who has taken over responsibility for it) could easily miss a one dot difference. Now suppose you wish to test `1 <= x < n` where `x` is a float. `1...n.include?(x)` does what you want, but there still is an argument for the more verbose `x >= 1 && x < n`,  because `1...n` could inadvertently be written or read as `1..n` and also for general readability. For these reasons I always use 2-dot ranges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are *not* the same thing.

```
(1..10).include?(10.5)
# => false
(1...11).include?(10.5)
# => true

(1..10).step(0.2).to_a
# => [1.0, 1.2, 1.4, ... 10.0]
(1...11).step(0.2).to_a
# => [1.0, 1.2, 1.4, ... 10.0, 10.2, 10.4, 10.6, 10.8] # (rounded for space)
```

And if you expect this to run 50% of the time, you are committing a (very tiny) error:

```
if (0..0.5).include?(rand())
```

which is equivalent to

```
if rand() <= 0.5
```

whereas these are true 50%:

```
if (0...0.5).include?(rand())
if rand() < 0.5
```

As Cary Swoveland notes, the two-dot literal creates a range that describes `start <= x <= finish`, while the three-dot literal creates a range with `exclude_end` set to `true`, which describes `start <= x < finish`.